# How to locally setup multiple projects on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to setup multiple projects on nginx locally.

These are my two server blocks:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/site1.dev/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name site1.dev;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/site2.dev/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name site2.dev;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Pinging site1.dev site2.dev will give a response.

In the browser going to localhost will redirect to site1.dev

Browsing to site1.dev will redirect to https://site1.dev and will return "This site can’t be reached"

Did I miss anything? According to the tuts these blocks are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better don't use `dev` domain.
[Chrome & Firefox now force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)